# MySQL Select into Multiple Variables Doesn't Work

Tags: mysql, function, variables

```
delimiter //
drop function if exists get_rating;
create function get_rating(id tinyint(1) unsigned) 
returns tinyint(1)

begin
    declare rating int unsigned;
    declare rating_count int unsigned;

    select sum(rating), count(rating)
    into rating, rating_count
    from comments
    where review_id = id;

    return rating_count;
end //

delimiter ;
```

When I call the function, neither rating nor rating_count returns the right value (3) they both return 0 when it should be adding three fields with values of 1. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Do you also have a column with name `id` in the table `comments` ?

Comment: @Ravinder No. As you can see from the function declaration it is a value passed in.

Answer (score 0):

There would be ambiguity on names of columns and local variables when they match by name.
You declared `rating` as variable but counting on a field with same name `rating` and assigning to again `rating`. It was causing an ambiguity.

Maintain them different.

Change your code as below:

```
delimiter //

drop function if exists get_rating //

create function 
         get_rating( _id tinyint(1) unsigned ) 
         returns tinyint(1)
begin
    declare _rating int unsigned;
    declare _rating_count int unsigned;

    select sum(rating), count(rating)
      into _rating, _rating_count
      from comments
     where review_id = _id;

    return _rating_count;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Can you post sample select * data on pastbin and give the link.